# Unable to read modified csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have exported a Excel file using the pandas `.to_csv` method on a 9-column DataFrame successfully, as well as accessing the created file with the `.to_csv` method likewise, with no errors whatsoever using the following code:

```
dfBase = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/Scripts/Base.csv',
                     sep=';', decimal=',', index_col=0, parse_dates=True,
                     encoding='utf-8', engine='python')
```

However, upon modifying the same CSV file manually using Notepad (which also extends to simply opening the file and saving it without making any actual alterations), pandas won't read it anymore, giving the following error message:

```
ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 2, saw 9
```

In the case of the modified CSV, if the `index_col=0` parameter is removed from the code, pandas is able to read the DataFrame again, however the first 8 columns become the index as a tuple and only the last column is brought as a field.

Could anyone point me out as to why I am unable to access the DataFrame after modifying it? Also, why does the removal of `index_col` enables its reading again with nearly all the columns as the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried opening and saving the file with some other text editor? Notepad really isn't that great, probably it's adding some special characters upon opening of the file or maybe the file already contains those characters and Notepad does not let you see them, hence pandas can't convert correctly

try Notepad++ or some more advanced IDEs like Atom, VSCode or PyCharm

Comment: The problem was indeed Notepad, SublimeText did the job as I needed, thanks